# Recording of Complete Works of Antonio Vivaldi

Tags: classical-music, reference-request

I am looking for a recording of Antonio Vivaldi's Complete Works. Does anybody here know where to get it from?

Comment: It is unclear to me, what you are searching: the list of works as shown in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compositions_by_Antonio_Vivaldi) or one of the official registers of his [works](https://web.archive.org/web/20080509095912/http://www.classical.net/music/composer/works/vivaldi/index.html)?

Comment: I am looking for a set of his works and where can I get it from, a box collection etc.

Answer (score 1):

Brilliant classics published a box with 66 CDs, see its [label catalogue](https://www.brilliantclassics.com/articles/v/vivaldi-edition/). This is probably the most comprehensive chunk one can order by a single ordering number, but also very likely just a fraction of his works.

[Naïve Classics](https://www.naiverecords.com/classique) has earned considerable merits by continuously expanding their catalogue, among others an ongoing project of digging out and recording the numerous operas written by Vivaldi, which can be checked on their [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/VivaldiEdition/) page.